# Java - cannot find class Checksum during compilation

Tags: java, checksum

My program failed to compile when I tried to run this statement:

```
Checksum checksum = new CRC32();
```

Error: cannot find symbol

symbol:   class Checksum

I have done the following at the beginning of the program.

```
import java.util.*;
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

make sure you imported the following

```
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.Checksum;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to import java.util.zip.* to use Checksum. Because its in the inner package and JVM don't go into deeper package

Answer (score 0):

Importing `java.util.*` doesn't import nested packages like `java.util.zip`, which `Checksum` and `CRC32` are part of. Use

```
import java.util.zip.*;
```

And you shouldn't get any compile errors. Also, you should use an IDE like Eclipse, as they automatically manage things like this for you.